# Databinding in WPF DataGrid (C# 4.0)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I'm just having a play with WPF, and I'm having a problem with databinding...

Here's my code so far...

The Window XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FRC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Registry Cleaner - By Martin Milan." MinHeight ="350" Height ="350" MinWidth="525" MaxHeight="700" Width="350" Background="#FFC199AA" >
    <DockPanel Background="#FFD9E1E8" Margin="10">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top"  >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >Filepath:</Label>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="txtFilePath" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
        </Grid>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
            <Button Name="butScan" Content="Scan" MinWidth="75" Margin="0,0,10,5" />
            <Button Name="butDelete" Content="Remove RegKeys" Margin="0,0,5,5" Click="butDelete_Click" />  
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="dgActions" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RegKeyPath, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Registry Key" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding DeletePath, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="Can I delete key?" 
                                            MinWidth="110" Width="110" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>    
        </ScrollViewer>

    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

The code behind for the window:

```
namespace FRC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        protected List<RegistryAction> mRegistryActions = new List<RegistryAction>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RegistryAction oRegAction = new RegistryAction();
            oRegAction.DeletePath = true;
            oRegAction.RegKeyPath = "A test value";
            mRegistryActions.Add (oRegAction);
            dgActions.DataContext = mRegistryActions;
            dgActions.ItemsSource = mRegistryActions;

        }

        private void butDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RegistryAction oRegAction = new RegistryAction();
            oRegAction.DeletePath = true;
            Random rGen = new Random();

            oRegAction.RegKeyPath = "A test " + rGen.Next(100).ToString();
            mRegistryActions.Add(oRegAction);

        }


    }
}
```

The RegistryAction class:

```
namespace FRC
{
    public class RegistryAction
    {
        public string RegKeyPath { get; set; }
        public bool DeletePath { get; set; }
        public RegistryAction()
        {
            this.DeletePath = false;
            this.RegKeyPath = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Basically. it sets up a list of RegistryAction objects, and binds it with a DataGrid. I am finding however that whenever I run the code in butDelete_Click, although the list is updated, the content isn't getting updated on the Grid.

In short, can anyone spot what I have missed please?

Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mRegistryActions` should be `ObservableCollection`:

```
protected ObservableCollection<RegistryAction> mRegistryActions = new ObservableCollection<RegistryAction>();
```

Comment: That sorted the problem completely in one foul swoop - cheers. Should have thought that if the grid isn't hearing about changes in the collection, then maybe the collection isn't shouting about them. +1 and accept.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `RegistryAction` implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). MSDN also has a [how-to on this subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx).

Comment: +1 - Cheers ... INotifyCollectionCHange would be needed as well on the List<T> - which of course I could always sub class...